# Sahi java driver select window

Tags: java, junit, popup, popupwindow, sahi

I'm having issues selecting a pop-up window when writing my tests using sahi java driver.

The process of the test searches for a user in a table, selects their record, a pop-up window appears with user information, but I can't find anything on the pop-up window to identify it by to then continue on with checks on the user window.

The window has no title in the header or name, using the sahi driver I previously used _getRecentWindow, but I'm stuck using java driver.

I've tried browser.focusWindow() but that focuses back to the default content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using the java driver? Any specific reason?

Comment: i want to work within a proper ide (i.e net beans), which is manageable rather than the script editor for sahi driver which, well isn't

Comment: Ok. Thing about this, would you rather get the automation work done easily with simple scripts, or you would prefer a proper ide? Also, I am not sure if you are using Sahi Pro or OS, but if you check the Pro version, you can find a nice way to edit scripts. This will get your work done for automation, which is what you will need while working with Sahi.

Comment: The reason I stress on this is because the Sahi scripts are way more powerful than the java driver and will get a lot done for you. This is how it was built and while using Sahi, if you want to leverage it, you must use Sahi scripting language. and if you look at it, it's just javascript, so you can take any ide which supports javascript and then associate .sah files with the js editor.

Comment: I'm using pro and as I have mentioned, I don't like the sahi script editor.

I'd need to write my code in a proper development environment, then load those tests into java controller and run from there, I want to get away from that. So, are there any suggestions as to where I could get some help? or is there no sahi java driver support?

Comment: Well in that case, your best bet would be send Sahi support an email. Even if you are evaluating or in case you are a customer, they will get you a solution. It's hard to understand from your question here as there are many kinds of popup windows. If it is a normal new browser window, _popup is the API you should look at.

Comment: Thank you.

Unfortunately it's not a popup window, have already tried browser.popup(); but doesn't work. It is a full browser window with handles, but just cant seem to find any identifier on the page.